# iPads stuck in Guided Access Mode

Tags: ios, guided-access

We have multiple kiosks running iOS 12 that have just become paper weights. Triple tapping the home button will not break guided Access mode. Force rebooting will return the iPad directly back into the kiosk app, where it still can't end guided access mode. They are bricked. This has happened to multiple devices starting two weeks ago. Any ideas?

Comment: When editing the entirety of the question, please ask a new question instead of replacing all the text. This question has been rolled back to a previous revision. [Learn more about community editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your devices are in **Single App Mode**- different from Guided Access. This is enabled through Apple Configurator or an MDM solution. To exit, connect the device to a Mac with [Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) installed. Then, select the device and the Actions menu (in the menu bar) select **Advanced - Stop Single App Mode**.

To re-enable kiosk mode, simply follow the same process, instead selecting **Start Single App Mode**.

**Note:** If Single App Mode was started using a configuration profile or MDM, you'll need to remove the profile, which can be done by selecting **Actions - Remove - Profiles...**

Comment: How can the Single App profile be removed if the ipad can't be accessed and we don't have Mac machines?

Comment: @Wake You need Configurator on a Mac, or access to whatever MDM was used to configure the iPads, many of which provide web interfaces accessible with a browser on a PC.

Comment: @grg - the ipads have no internet connection. The whole reason we need to break single app mode is to go into wifi settings.

Comment: @Wake Then it looks like Configurator is your way forwards, using a USB connection. If Single App Mode was easy to break out of, it wouldn’t be safe to use as a kiosk!

Comment: Simply dropping the internet connection and bricking the device is a terrible loophole though. Wireless devices lose their wifi connections all the time for a million little reasons.

Comment: Which is why it is assumed you have a mac handy to break the loop if needed. You *did* need a mac to supervise the devices, so it is assumed you continue to have one handy.

Comment: There's no Mac machine involved. We have windows machines and a web-based MDM that applied the single app profile remotely by liaising with an Apple DEP. Now we can't access them remotely, hence the unbreakable conundrum.